# Mockk verify spy of method with lambda argument

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, mockk

Im trying to verify that my method `doRequestImpl()` has been called 3 times in my test - It has the signature: `suspend fun <T> doRequestImpl(handler: suspend () -> T): T`

In my test i have:

```
coVerify(exactly = 3) {
    sut.doRequestImpl(any())
}
```

`sut` is a spy of a real class implementation.

But something is not right, as with a debugger i can see that the `coVerify()` actually does a call to `sut.doRequestImpl()` using a `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1`-type as argument which throws an exception and making the test to fail.

What am i doing wrong? Im guessing my argument matcher is not the right one but....?